# Is it okay to leave cooked octopus in water till next morning?

Tags: octopus

I've cooked octopus in a boiling water (well, more like in own juice to be more precise) like I usually do and than I've realized that I'm too tired and going to eat it tomorrow morning. My question is: what would be the better option - to take it out of water or to keep it there?

I don't now what happens with cooked octopus left in a water for about 8-10 hours.

Just to clarify - it's question about keeping it in water and not about room temp. In my experience nothing happens with a hot pot slowly boiling down till morning - however I am actually going to put it to refrigerator after all.

Comment: I assume you mean that this will be under refrigeration?  Maybe clarify your question.

Comment: @moscafj actually, most likely not, it's cold enough to keep it till morning not in refrigerator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know if food left at room temperature is still safe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat)

Comment: I think there are two questions here:  (a) should it be kept at room temp (probably not, and thus a duplicate), and (b) is it better to store cooked octopus in the cooking water or not (under refrigeration - this is an interesting question).

Comment: @moscafj edited the question to make it clear that it's actually  about b, so it's not a dup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've realized that the price of mistake is not the high anyways so I've just divided cooked octopus to two parts: one left in water, another one not. This morning I finally have an answer!

**It's better to take cooked octopus out of water but it won't be a tragedy if you didn't.**

While both meals were tasty, octopus left in water was slightly slimy - it was a very subtle difference however noticeable.